# Coordinates geometry / How to assign point_dist with distance between points (x1 y1) and (x2 y2)?

Tags: python

Assign point_dist with distance between points (x1 y1) and (x2 y2)?

Distance = sqrt(x2 - x1) and (y2 - y1)

program will be tested with inputs: 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0

points distance 3.0

So new I am still trying to comprehend.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first to define correctly the distance function ([https://byjus.com/maths/distance-between-two-points-formula/][1]).

If you are not familiar with numpy and any python code, you can do the following:

```
import math

x1 = 1
y1 = 2
x2 = 1
y2 = 5

point_dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
point_dist
```

Otherwise here is the python code with numpy, it works for any dimension. Here p2 - p1 do the substraction like as vectors, elementwise, and **2 make the power of each element in the vector. The sum function add every element together.

```
import numpy as np

def get_distance(p1, p2):
    return np.sqrt(sum((p2 - p1)**2))

p1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
p2 = np.array([1.0, 5.0])

point_dist = get_distance(p1, p2)
```